# Constructing squares using linear operations when a sizeable residue is given

Tags: nt.number-theory

Given $x\in\{0,1,\dots,2^k-1\}$ and given $x^2\bmod p$ where $p$ is a prime at in $[2^k,2^{k+1}]$ is it possible to construct $x^2$ using only at most $O(2^{k})$ linear in $x$ operations (that is operations of form $x^2$ are disallowed but operations of form $ax+b$ are allowed were $a,b$ are constants) where we are allowed to pick $O(2^{k})$ constants ($a,b$ in example before)?

Comment: This question isn't clear. Are you looking for some algorithm or a proof it can't exist? Could you specify the inputs, restrictions, and outputs in more detail? Is it some other computation model? Could you describe it in more detail?

Comment: Inputs: $k,x,p, x^2\bmod p$ and output is $x^2$.

Comment: Why can't the algorithm just take $x$ and square it? You say that isn't allowed, but how do you prevent it from looking at its bits and doing it anyway?

Comment: We avoid non-linear operations.

Comment: So you want a circuit with the gates of multiplication by a constant and addition? Anything else?

Comment: That is pretty much it.

Comment: Well, this can only compute linear functions of the input, and $x^2$ isn't one (you can look at a few different inputs, represent one of them as a linear combination of the others, and see that value you get for $x^2$ is wrong), so I'm not sure I understand the question.